# How to add rows and columns to a table in asp.net dynamically in button

Tags: asp.net, button, rows

I intend to create a dynamic table with the proviso that every time I click on the button I can add a row to that table.

I'm using the following code but it does not work.

For the first time I click on the button runs, but for the second time that must be added the second row it does not do so, and only one row is added to the previous.

In page

```
DropDownList[] dlsathetasilat = new DropDownList[50];
    Label[] lblradif = new Label[50];
    TextBox[] txtreshtetahsili = new TextBox[50];
    TextBox[] txtmoasese = new TextBox[50];
    TextBox[] txtcity = new TextBox[50];
    TextBox []txtdateakhz = new TextBox[50];
    CheckBox[] chmadrakmoadel = new CheckBox[50];

    TableCell []tc = new TableCell[7];

   static int i=0;
```

In button :

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
           lblradif[i] = new Label();
           lblradif[i].Text = (i + 1).ToString();
           lblradif[i].CssClass = "lbl";
           dlsathetasilat[i] = new DropDownList();
           dlsathetasilat[i].Items.Add("دیپلم");
           dlsathetasilat[i].CssClass = "dl";

           txtreshtetahsili[i] = new TextBox();
           txtreshtetahsili[i].CssClass = "dl";
           txtmoasese[i] = new TextBox();
           txtmoasese[i].CssClass = "dl";
           txtdateakhz[i] = new TextBox();
           txtdateakhz[i].CssClass = "dl";
           txtcity[i] = new TextBox();
           txtcity[i].CssClass = "dl";
           chmadrakmoadel[i] = new CheckBox();
           chmadrakmoadel[i].CssClass = "d2";


           for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
               tc[k] = new TableCell();

           tc[0].Controls.Add(lblradif[i]);
           tc[1].Controls.Add(dlsathetasilat[i]);
           tc[2].Controls.Add(txtreshtetahsili[i]);
           tc[3].Controls.Add(txtmoasese[i]);
           tc[4].Controls.Add(txtcity[i]);
           tc[5].Controls.Add(txtdateakhz[i]);
           tc[6].Controls.Add(chmadrakmoadel[i]);

           for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
               tr.Controls.Add(tc[j]);

           Table1.Rows.Add(tr);

           i++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue of PostBack and ViewState. ASP.NET does not save the ViewState for Table control. Which means if you want to keep the table data during the post back, you need to bind the table on every post back.

What you can do is save the table values in a ViewState object. Then write a function which creates the table by using the ViewState object. In the on click event of the button, add additional rows to the view state object and then call the function again to recreate the table. This looks quite simple, but the main problem is that if you have additional controls in the table, like TextBox, DropDownList etc. then they do not retain the values after postback, becuase we are recreating the table every time.

By looking at all these problems, I would  consider using DataBound controls like Repeater with which you can build the table based on the number of rows that you want to create. Also you can deal with the dynamic controls if you want.